# php odbc double excecutions bug

Tags: php, odbc, wamp

I am using Windows Server with MSSQL Server 2008, and a ODBC connection to WAMP on a seperate Windows Server.
Using PHP to execute database queries, and when I run INSERT queries I get two identical rows (with unique identifier as the only thing seperating them).
I have checked multiple times that it's not double posting, so it must be executing the code twice, or sending it twice, the problem is not on the PHP side, that's for sure.

For example, I run this code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable(aboutPerson, fromPerson, comment)
VALUES(1,5, 'hello')";
//.. create connection to db
odbc_exec($sql);
//.. close connection to db
```

Out of that I get two identical rows in the table. This occurs on several tables.

Why does this occur and how can I stop it from happening? Is it a known bug in connecting WAMP to Microsoft SQL Server with ODBC?

BTW, I don't have the option of switching systems.

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Edit-

An actual example by request.

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO billboard (toPersonId, toGroupClass, toOfficeId, fromOfficeId,
fromType, fromId, header, msg, aboutPersonId, created, startMessageId,
fromPersonId, status, emailNote, smsNote) 
VALUES (1, 0, 1, 1,
2, 1, 'cccccccccccccc', 'cccccccccccccccc', '', GETDATE(), 0,
1, 0, 0, 0)";
$resource = odbc_connect(database server url, username, password);
$statement = odbc_exec($SQL, $resource);
return odbc_free_result($statement);
```

I execute this code and I should get only 1 single row inserted into the table. Instead I get this, two identical rows (except for the first column, which is the primary key and is identity)

```
111 1   0   1   1   2   1   cccccccccccccc  cccccccccccccccc    0   2012-10-10 12:56:27.773 0   1   0   0   0
110 1   0   1   1   2   1   cccccccccccccc  cccccccccccccccc    0   2012-10-10 12:56:27.773 0   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: can you post some more code, because it is not helpful.